# Where to place a note number within a list

Tags: punctuation, footnotes

If I need to include an explanatory footnote for one item within a list, where does the number go? I know that under normal circumstances, the number would go after the comma at the end of a clause. However, in this case, the note doesn't occur at the end of a clause or sentence and placing it at the end of the sentence would introduce confusion. So which example would be proper?

Ex 1.   The characteristics of the transition itself, which include role change (gain or loss), psychological affect (positive or negative)<sup>3</sup>, source of transition (internal or external), timing (on-time or off-time), duration (permanent, temporary, or uncertain), and degree of stress.

Ex 2. The characteristics of the transition itself, which include role change (gain or loss), psychological affect (positive or negative),<sup>3</sup> source of transition (internal or external), timing (on-time or off-time), duration (permanent, temporary, or uncertain), and degree of stress.

Comment: They both look the same to me.

Comment: Wikipedia puts footnotes after punctuation, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: This is a question of style and is not dictated by language. You should consult a style guide for whatever entity you're writing for.

Comment: Some guides only want notes at the end of a sentence but it varies a lot.

Comment: You do not show a list.

Comment: Why not ask your own editor or publisher?

Answer (score 1):

Commas and semi-colons separate list items. The reference number is relevant to an item in the list, so it's entirely reasonable to keep it with its item, before the comma. It should certainly be as close as possible to the term which it refers to.

For example (and adding a couple of numbers for further illustration),

> The characteristics of the transition itself, which include role<sup>1</sup> change (gain or loss), psychological affect<sup>2</sup> (positive or negative)<sup>3</sup>, source of transition (internal or external), timing (on-time or off-time), duration (permanent, temporary, or uncertain), and degree of stress.

Compare to

> The characteristics of the transition itself, which include:
>
> - role<sup>1</sup> change (gain or loss)
> - psychological affect<sup>2</sup> (positive or negative)<sup>3</sup>
> - source of transition (internal or external)
> - timing (on-time or off-time)
> - duration (permanent, temporary, or uncertain), and
> - degree of stress.

You wouldn't put the <sup>3</sup> anywhere else in that list; treat a comma-separated list similarly.

Comment: OK, so you're suggesting that the note number in my scenario go after the word affect and before the parenthetical aside (and thus also before the comma)? If so, that seems reasonable to me.

Comment: So, more broadly then, would placing the note number before the comma, such for an item in a list, be proper because it refers only to the preceding word wheras placing it after the comma, such as at the end of a clause, would denote that the note number refers to the entire preceding clause? If that is true, then would it not be fair to say that the note number goes immediately after the element of the sentence that it references, including any relevant punctuation belonging to that element of the sentence?

Comment: This is true for some citation styles but not all. [MHRA style](https://librarydevelopment.group.shef.ac.uk/referencing/mhra-footnotes.html) says footnote numbers should preferably go at the end of a sentence; while Chicago is keen on having them closer to the relevant clause or quote. So it's a matter of style where they go.

Comment: Style manuals, alas, often seem to be aiming more on giving the printed text a certain visual appeal, than on enabling the authors to precisely convey the logical structure of the subject matter. If the publication one is writing for requires that a certain style manual be followed, one may have no choice in the matter, but an author who is not bound by a style manual in this respect, is likely to care more about the latter aim and to use footnotes in the way recommended in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of style. Here, *The Chicago Manual of Style* weighs in:

> Please see [*CMOS*
> 14.26](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part3/ch14/psec026.html)
> [login required]: “A note number should generally be placed at the end
> of a sentence or at the end of a clause. The number normally follows a
> quotation (whether it is run into the text or set as an extract).
> Relative to other punctuation, the number follows any punctuation mark
> except for the dash, which it precedes.” Paragraph 14.26 also includes
> examples.
>  <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of Style Online*—Style
> Q&A](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0020.html)</sub>

At 14.26, this is one of the examples offered:

> It was the hour of “national paths” toward socialism;<sup>9</sup> but
> that expression, which turned out to be temporary, was more an
> incantation than a discovery.

So your second example would be correct in *CMOS* style:

> . . . psychological affect (positive or
> negative),<sup>3</sup> . . .